# Não consigo obter resultado da minha lista de objetos atualizada

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebird

Estou desenvolvendo o back de um serviço web e vai ser minha primeira aplicação em NodeJS v11. Não repararem na falta de separação de 'regras de negocio' com 'manipulação do banco' pois estou tendo problemas pra fazer essa boa prática com Firebird. De qualquer maneira, vamos ao problema do código:

```
module.exports = function(express) {

express.get('/folha', (req, res) => {
    const firebird = require('node-firebird');
    const config = express.config.dbconfig; 

    let listaTudo = [{FORA: 1}]; //Atribuí esse objeto pra saber que ele foi inclido FORA!


    firebird.attach(config, (err, db) => { 
        if (err)
            throw err;

        //GET QUANTIDADE FUNCIONARIOS ATIVOS DA EMPRESA
         db.query("SELECT COUNT(*) AS ATIVOS FROM FUNCCONTRATO WHERE CODIGOEMPRESA = '501' AND DATADEM IS NULL", (err, result /*27*/) => {
            if (err)
                throw err;

            listaTudo.push(result[0]); //Alimentando a listaTudo com resultado { ATIVOS: 27 }
            console.log('result:', result);  // [ { ATIVOS: 27 } ]
            console.log('listaTudo:',listaTudo);  // [ { FORA: 1 }, { ATIVOS: 27 } ] 
            listaTudo.push({DENTRO: 2}); //Alimentando a lista com { DENTRO : 2 } 
            console.log('listaTudo:',listaTudo);  // [ { FORA: 1 }, { ATIVOS: 27 } , { DENTRO : 2 } ]

            db.detach(); // DESCONECTA DO BANCO
        });
        console.log(listaTudo); //OBTIDO:  [ { FORA: 1 } ]  ------ ESPERADO: [ { FORA: 1 }, { ATIVOS: 27 } , { DENTRO : 2 } ]
        res.send(listaTudo); //OBTIDO:  [ { FORA: 1 } ]  ------ ESPERADO: [ { FORA: 1 }, { ATIVOS: 27 } , { DENTRO : 2 } ]
    });
});
```

};

Pois bem, dei uma olhada sobre JavaScript ser um código que funciona de forma síncrona, talvez por isso ele imprimi a saída do `console.log()` e `res.send()` nas linhas 27 e 28 respectivamente de forma não atualizada como aconteceu dentro da função `db.query('sql, result =>)` nas linhas 15 a 26.

Quero fazer isso pois ao acessar `/folha` quero que retorne no response uma lista de resultados de querys que fiz, mas não estou conseguindo alimentar a lista, ou se estou, não estou conseguindo acessa-la pós alimenta-la.

Alguém entende o que possa ser feito?

Comment: A primeira coisa a fazer é postar o código como texto e não como imagem. Informe também a versão do `Node` que você está utilizando

Comment: Obrigado pela dica!! Já editei :D

Comment: Alguma resposta ajudou a resolver o problema e pode sanar dúvidas similares de outros usuários? Caso positivo não esqueça de marcar a resposta como aceita. Pra fazer isso é só clicar no ✓ do lado esquerdo da mesma (abaixo do indicador de up e down votes).

Comment: Opa, fiz isso agora que você comentou. Agradeço a paciência, caro colega de UTFPR. Como disse, era meu primeiro post no fórum. Não sabia o que fazer pós obter a solução.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O problema é que a requisição é assíncrona. Ou você insere o `res.send` dentro do `callback` do `db.query` ou reescreve utilizando `promise`:

```
const firebird = require('node-firebird');

const attach = (config) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    firebird.attach(config, (err, db) => {
      if (err) reject(err);
      else resolve(db);
    });
  });
};

const query = (db, sql) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    db.query(sql, (err, result) => {
      if (err) reject(err);
      else resolve(result);
    });
  });
};

const listar = async (req, res, config) => {
  const lista = [{ FORA: 1 }]; //Atribuí esse objeto pra saber que ele foi inclido FORA!
  const db = await attach(config);
  const result = await query(db, "SELECT COUNT(*) AS ATIVOS FROM FUNCCONTRATO WHERE CODIGOEMPRESA = '501' AND DATADEM IS NULL");
  lista.push(result[0]); //Alimentando a lista com resultado { ATIVOS: 27 }
  console.log('result:', result);  // [ { ATIVOS: 27 } ]
  console.log('lista:', lista);  // [ { FORA: 1 }, { ATIVOS: 27 } ]
  lista.push({ DENTRO: 2 }); //Alimentando a lista com { DENTRO : 2 }
  console.log('lista:',lista);  // [ { FORA: 1 }, { ATIVOS: 27 } , { DENTRO : 2 } ]
  db.detach();
  res.send(lista);
};

module.exports = (express) => express.get('/folha', async (req, res) => listar(req, res, express.config.dbconfig));
```

Comment: Vou ter que dar uma estudada sobre Promises e Async/Await pelo visto.
Em tese esse seu código refatorado pro meu problema tem que fazer alguma mudança pra rodar aqui? Pois troquei por ele e gera um(ns) erro(s). 

De qualquer maneira, muito obrigado pela ajuda e atenção (pela edição no post principal também)

Comment: @ThalesH.P.deLira quais erros?

Comment: UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: self.execute is not a function

    at Database.query (c:\node-projetos\TestesBancoDePaula\node_modules\node-firebird\lib\index.js:1571:10)
   
 at Promise (internal/util.js:290:30)
 at new Promise (<anonymous>)at internal/util.js:289:12
    at listar (c:\node-projetos\TestesBancoDePaula\app\routes\funcionario.js:9:24)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/next_tick.js:81:5)

Comment: @ThalesH.P.deLira fiz uma alteração que talvez resolva o erro que você descreveu